# Powershell - Unable to look for a registry value

Tags: powershell, registry, uninstallation

I have McAfee Drive Encryption installed on my Machine and trying to query the application using Powershell, however there is a really strange issue happening.

When i go the Uninstall Key in the registry, i can see McAfee Drive Encryption there, however it does not find it when i run the following command:

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Where { $_.DisplayName -match "McAfee Drive" } | select DisplayName, DisplayVersion
```

now i tried to simply put the code as: `Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`

and it lists all the applications in there but not the McAfee Value!, i have tried this on another account / Machine and that worked fine, so wondering if anyone had a similar issue at all?

Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you certain that it uses the registry for that information? Not everything does, apparently.

Comment: Does the program support a per-user install? If you have installed it per-user, then query `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`

Comment: thank you guys

Yes, because when trying the same command on another username it works, even though the installation in in HKLM, we can see when checking manually, but powershell does not seem to find it for some reason

Comment: You can see the key in RegEdit, right? Check the permissions on that key vs. a key that shows up in your query of all entries. Also, have you tried `Get-Item 'HKLM\...\Uninstall\<McAfee GUID>'`?

Comment: Thats solved thank you, it was indeed a permission issue